# How to overwrite Twitter Bootstrap navbar-inner class

Tags: css, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap

I like to have the navbar-inner element in my Bootstrap Layout to be customizable by the jQuery UI framework.

```
<div class="navbar-inner ui-widget-header">

</div>
```

But the background of the navbar is always black. 
How can overwrite the Bootstrap Background with the background from the ui-widget-header class without changing the bootstrap css file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create your own CSS file which you will use to overwrite styles from the bootstrap.css and add its reference to your HTML after the reference to bootstrap.css.  Also, to ensure that your styles overwrite the bootstrap ones you can use the !important keyword in your css.

So, create a CSS file and call it something like bootstrap-overwrite.css.

Add the bootstrap class you want to overwrite -

```
.navbar-inner
{
  background: none !important;
}
```

Add the reference to your HTML after the bootstrap reference -

```
<link href="styles/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="styles/bootstrap-overwrite.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Twitter Bootstrap is a framework that is supposed to be restyled so you shouldn't be afraid of overwriting the default styling.

Comment: Does this apply for "-responsive.css" styles?

Answer (score 1):

Make the `ui-widget-header` selector more [*specific*](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#specificity), so that it overrides `navbar-inner` in [the cascade](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#cascade). For example,

```
#pageid .navbar .ui-widget-header {
    background: red;
}
```

Is more *specific* than simply...

```
.ui-widget-header {
    background: red;
}
```

Comment: The styles for ui-widget-header are generated by jqueryui themeroller, And I don't like to manipulate the generated css from both frameworks (bootstrap.css, jquery-ui.css) because it should be easy themeable for different instances.

Comment: Must admit I had assumed it was just the `navbar-inner` class that you were unable to change. If you cannot change any of the current CSS and you want both these classes applied to the element then I see no way of making this work as you require. In this case, the only way to influence the background would be to add additional CSS and/or use JavaScript to modify the styles but this won't be able to influence `ui-widget-header`.

Comment: I found a solution. I add the ui-widget-header class to an child div of the navbar-inner div. Now it is working with some simple css overwriting like set color of ".navbar .nav > li > a" to inherit and padding-left and padding right of navbar-inner to 0.

Comment: Ah OK - change the HTML - didn't think of that! :)